# ICollection does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, types

I am trying to check whether a [`SearchResultEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchresultentry(v=vs.110).aspx) contains a certain attribute. For this, I am trying the following code:

```
if(searchResultEntry.Attributes.AttributeNames.Contains(propertyName))
```

but this fails with the error

> `ICollection` does not contain a definition for `Contains`,  and the best extension method overload "`Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>, string)`" requires a receiver of type "`IQueryable<string>`".

I also tried to make it an `IQueryable` using `AttributeNames.AsQueryable()`, but on that `IQueryable`, `Contains` is not available as well.

What is wrong here? When IntelliSense tells me something is available, but then, when I got to that very type, it is still unavailable, am I missing some references or using directives?

Comment: Non-generic IQueryable and ICollection don't have a Contains method. The generic versions do.

Comment: `ICollection` is weakly typed and as such not very LINQy. Throw in a [`Cast<string>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406) to get the rest of the goodness. Note, however, that `Attributes.Contains(propertyName)` should also work, since [there's a method for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchresultattributecollection.contains).